# RobotFramework throwing an error if path doesn't include separator

Tags: python, robotframework

- RobotFramework version: 6.0.2
- Python version: 3.9.10
- OS version: Mac Ventura 13.2.1

Lately, I've been seeing strange errors when doing directory functions with Robot. The latest one I keep running into is with `Join Path`

My code used is normally written like so:

```
${logs_file} =  Join Path  ${logs_dir}  somesystem.log.0
```

But I've started receiving an error stating:

```py
TypeError: replace() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

However, if I force the separator, it runs fine:

```
${logs_file} =  Join Path  ${logs_dir}/  somesystem.log.0
```

The `TypeError` is obviously from Python, so Robot is not parsing the elements correctly.

It would seem that `${logs_dir}` is being sent as two arguments, but `${logs_dir}/` is sent as one. Outputting `${logs_dir}` shows the correct path; no spaces, no funky characters, and no slash at the end.

Has anyone else seen this? Or do I now have to go through all my code and append slashes to dir variables?

Comment: Can you paste code that reproduces your problem? In the first line, use `Set variable` to set  ${logs_dir} to the value that gives you this error, and the second line is as it is.